# Tell Jackson about a new type with "content" for @JsonSerialize(contentUsing=...)

Tags: java, jackson

I am using a third-party library that defines an `Option` class, which is similar to `java.util.Optional`.  In one case, it holds a type that needs a custom deserializer.  With `Optional`, I could write

```
class StdContainer {
    @JsonDeserialize(contentUsing=MyDeserializer.class)
    @JsonSerialize(contentUsing=MySerializer.class)
    Optional<MyClass> content;
}
```

and Jackson will using my custom serializer/deserializer on the class.

With the third party library, I tried writing

```
class ThirdPartyContainer {
    @JsonDeserialize(contentUsing=MyDeserializer.class)
    @JsonSerialize(contentUsing=MySerializer.class)
    Option<MyClass> content;
}
```

This serializes MyClass using the default serializer, which makes sense, since I would not expect Jackson to know about the third-party library.  Is there a way to tell Jackson that a particular class is a container and that it should use `contentUsing` on that class?  I would expect that this also involves telling Jackson how to get the content.

Answer (score 0):

The way `Optional`s (from Guava, Java 8, Scala) are recognized as containers is by them registering `TypeModifier`: this makes Jackson recognize them as somewhat special (actual type is `ReferenceType`).
To see how these work you could have a look at, say, `jackson-datatype-guava`. Once type is refined actual serializer/deserializer implementation is quite simple: `jackson-databind` has base implementations that provide about 90% of handling (see, for example `AtomicReferenceSerializer` and `AtomicReferenceDeserializer` in `jackson-databind`).

Use cases like these are actually big reason why Jackson module interface was added, to allow development and sharing of datatype modules for 3rd party types, so that once maintainers of a datatype lib (or community) provides such module, other users can simply plug it in and things "just work"